# UIBarButtonItem appearance how to remove text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

I am customizing my nag bar button in iOS7 and I am using the following code:

```
// Customizing the NavBar Buttons
UIImage * btHome = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 3, 0, 3)];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:btHome forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

It is working, but the view shows my home button with the button text over it, I do not want the text to show.

What else do I need to do to remove the text?

What I have is shown here:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question. Just don't set the text?

Comment: LOL, yes, I tried that, maybe I am tired, been up awhile, but if I clear the text in IB the button does not show and if I use self.title=@""; or self.parentViewController.text=@""; the text still shows in both iOS 6 and iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

1) text color on a bar button item through appearance

2) use setImage: instead of setBackgroundImage: and do not use resizable image

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code. May be it will help you.

```
UIImage *faceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back_arrow.png"];
UIButton *yourbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
yourbutton.bounds = CGRectMake( 10, 0, faceImage.size.width, faceImage.size.height );
[yourbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[yourbutton setImage:faceImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:yourbutton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sets the back button title offset for given bar metrics

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -60) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: This solution works sort of, but it does not change the frame of the back button's title, causing alignment issues on smaller screens.